# disabling Line chart categories group sorting alphabetically

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

How can following be displayed according to "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday .... .. Saturday" ?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long,  I found it finally:
Right click on Category group and go to "Category group properties".
Go to "Sorting" and delete all selected sorting options..

This worked for me..  Below are screen shots..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ways possible

(i)You have to manually swap the X axis

(ii)Using IValueConverter

Follow the link,

[Format Axis using IValueConverter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/12/pineapple-upside-down-chart-how-to-invert-the-axis-of-a-chart-for-smaller-is-better-scenarios.aspx)

Comment: I have already fed my dataset as source . when I pass it, I pass in correct order eg (sunday, monday .. saturday) but my display is not in proper order. Thank you for your answer but it was not appropriate answer that helped me.

Comment: dtt is my datatable:

            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Sunday", "Hours", 10 });
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Monday", "Hours", 14 });
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Tuesday", "Hours", 9 });
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Wednesday", "Hours", 6 });
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Thursday", "Hours", 4});
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Friday", "Hours", 10 });
            dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Saturday", "Hours", 4 });